Manhwa where the female lead is reincarnated as a holy spirit; spirits are ranked by numbers based on their strength, and she is the weakest
I'm not sure if this was all in my head, but I remember a manhwa with the following plot:
The female lead reincarnated as a holy spirit or something like that. These spirits are ranked by numbers based on their strength, and she is the weakest. They have to partner with a human, as all the spirits do, and she becomes the partner of the knight captain, I believe. She remembers that, in the original story, she's meant to die. I'm pretty sure she forms a harem by accident, but she wants to be left alone.
Does anyone know of this, or am I going crazy?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.
